# Dropping rows based on conditional values from 2 columns

Tags: python, conditional-statements, drop

I have a DataFrame with 2 columns: "name" and "retailtype". "name" presents the name of a location, and "retailtype" represents the general type of retail that happens in that location.

What I need to do is the following: For the rows where "retailtype" equals "settlement_with_key_retail_centre", I want to drop all the rows whose "name" column does not equal 'Glasgow', 'Edinburgh', 'Aberdeen', 'Dundee', 'Inverness' or 'PerthStirling'

The code I was writing is:

```py
cities_to_consider = ['Glasgow', 'Edinburgh', 'Aberdeen', 'Dundee', 'Inverness', 'PerthStirling']

if shopping_centres['retailtype'] == 'settlement_with_key_retail_centre' :
    shopping_centres = shopping_centres.drop( shopping_centres.loc[ (shopping_centres['name'](cities_to_consider))])
```

But it does not seem to work.

Can anyone tell me what would be the best way to solve this issue? I thought of iterating over rows in the DataFrame, but a few answers here in Stack Overflow suggest that is not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Try to index the rows that you want to drop, then reverse the index.

```
rows_you_want_to_drop = df.loc[
    (DROP_CONDITION_A) & (DROP_CONDITION_B)
]
```

This will give you a DataFrame containing only rows that you want to drop. Now you can reverse the given condition from `df.loc[CONDITION]` to `df.loc[~CONDITION]`:

```
rows_you_want_to_save = df.loc[
    ~((DROP_CONDITION_A) & (DROP_CONDITION_B))
]
```

In your case, the two drop conditions will be a conjunction of the following two:

```
df.retailtype == 'settlement_with_key_retail_centre'
~df.name.isin(['Glasgow', 'Edinburgh', 'Aberdeen', 'Dundee', 'Inverness', 'PerthStirling'])
```

And yes, iterating over rows is usually a bad idea because it is relatively slower; try reading pandas documentations on DataFrame.loc and indexing, it will help you a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

index_names = df[ (df['retailtype'] == 'settlement_with_key_retail_centre') & (~df.name.isin(['Glasgow', 'Edinburgh','Aberdeen', 'Dundee', 'Inverness', 'PerthStirling']))].index

df.drop(index_names, inplace = True)

The above lines should give you the desired output